# Match the sets between two column in a row

Tags: python, pandas

I have table with two columns:

| Col_1 | Col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 3,4,5 | 3,5 |
| 8,9,12 | 8,9,12 |
| 8,9,12 |  |

I need to check Col_1 with Col_2 and if an element in Col_1 is present in Col_2 then save True, else save False.

The output table should be:

| Col_1 | Col_2 | Check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3,4,5 | 3,5 | True,False,True |
| 8,9,12 | 8,9,12 | True,True,True |
| 8,9,12 |  | False,False,False |

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension with test splitted values:

```
df['check'] = [[z in y for z in x] for x, y in zip(df['Col_1'].fillna('').str.split(','), 
                                                   df['Col_2'].fillna('').str.split(','))]
print (df)
    Col_1   Col_2                  check
0   3,4,5     3,5    [True, False, True]
1  8,9,12  8,9,12     [True, True, True]
2  8,9,12    None  [False, False, False]
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and test valeus per groups:

```
df['check'] = (df.assign(Col_1 = df['Col_1'].fillna('').str.split(','), 
                         Col_2 = df['Col_2'].fillna('').str.split(','))
                 .explode('Col_1')
                 .groupby(level=0)
                 .apply(lambda x: list(x.Col_1.isin(x.Col_2.iat[0]))))
print (df)
    Col_1   Col_2                  check
0   3,4,5     3,5    [True, False, True]
1  8,9,12  8,9,12     [True, True, True]
2  8,9,12    None  [False, False, False]
```

Comment: Can you please explain this part of the code [z in y for z in x] ?

Comment: @NoviK - Sure, for each value of list generated from `Col_1` variable `x` test if match values generated from `Col2`, variable `y`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df.fillna("", inplace=True)

df["Check"] = df.apply(
 lambda x: pd.Series(x["Col_1"].split(",")).isin(x["Col_2"].split(",")).values, axis=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.fillna('')
df['check'] = df.apply(lambda row: ','.join(str(x in row.Col_2.split(',')) 
                                            for x in row.Col_1.split(',')), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Col_1   Col_2              check
0   3,4,5     3,5    True,False,True
1  8,9,12  8,9,12     True,True,True
2  8,9,12          False,False,False
```